# Generation of strict contraction semigroups

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, elliptic-pde, semigroups-of-operators, contraction-mapping

Let $T(t)$ be a $C_0$-semigroup on Banach space $X$, and $A$ its generator. By Lumer-Philipps theorem we know that if $A$ is densely defined and m-dissipative operator then it generates a $C_0$-semigroup of contractions, i.e., $$\|T(t)\| \leq 1, \quad \forall t \geq 0.$$
My question here: is there any theorem which gives conditions to generate a strictly contraction $C_0$-semigroup? That is, 
$$\|T(t)\| < 1, \quad \forall t > 0.$$
For example, for $A=\Delta$ the Dirichlet Laplacian, is the associated semigroup strictly contractive? Can we calculate the norm $\|T(t)\|$ in this case? Or at least, Is $I-T(t)$ invertible? If this is true for the Dirichlet laplacian, can we obtain the same result for second order elliptic operator?

Comment: It can't be true for $t = 0$ or you don't have a semigroup...

Comment: For the Laplacian, assuming you only want it for $t > 0$, this is basically equivalent to showing that the lowest eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ of $\Delta$ is strictly positive, i.e. there is a spectral gap. Then you immediately get $\|T(t)\| \le e^{-\lambda t}$ by the spectral theorem.

Comment: See also the [Hille-Yosida theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hille%E2%80%93Yosida_theorem) and try to apply it with $\omega < 0$.

Comment: Yeah, sure for t>0. I understand that it's true for the $\Delta$, is it true for $-A$ where $A$ is a second order elliptic operator ?

Comment: For Hille-Yosida theorem, why there exists $\omega<0$ in this case ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your conditions is for contraction semigroups equivalent to have uniform exponential stability, i.e., to have growth bound less than zero, see [Proposition V.1.7](https://www.math.uni-tuebingen.de/arbeitsbereiche/agfa/members/rana/engelnagel_oneparametersemigroups.pdf). in

*Engel, Klaus-Jochen; Nagel, Rainer*, [**One-parameter semigroups for linear evolution equations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/b97696), Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 194. Berlin: Springer. xxi, 586 p. (2000). [ZBL0952.47036](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0952.47036).

Assuming you work in a Hilbert space, you can reformulate the Lumer.Phillips theorem for your case as
$$\Re \langle Ax,x\rangle \leq \omega<0$$
to get a sufficient condition. For many examples you can test this by applying some version of Green's theorem.

For second order elliptic operators on bounded domains it boils down to look at the eigenvalues. If they are negative, you have exponential stability.

ADDED after comments:
For uniformly elliptic operator it all depends on the boundary conditions. Neumann boundary conditions imply that you do not have all negative eigenvalues.

If you are interested in the spectral theory of differential operators, there are many good books. I liked [the one](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511623721)

*Davies, E. B.*, Spectral theory and differential operators, Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics. 42. Cambridge: Cambridge Univ. Press. ix, 182 p. (1995). [ZBL0893.47004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0893.47004).

very much, it is a good start.

Comment: Why the strict contractivity is equivalent to uniform exponential stability ? If $\|T(t)\| <1, t>0$ we have not necessary $\|T(t)\| \leq e^{- \varepsilon t},$ for some $\varepsilon >0$, which is equivalent to have growth bound less than zero.

Comment: In other way, my question: is there any semigroup associated with a second order elliptic operator such that $\|T(t)\| =1,$ at least for some $t>0$ ? If not that means that for every such semigroup we have $I-T(t)$ is invertible.

Comment: @S.Cho: yes, we do. I added a reference for this.

Comment: Thank you sir for the appreciable reference. Now, I understand the link between the two notions. But I'm still confused, Is there any semigroup associated with a second order elliptic operator on a bounded domain such that $I-T(t)$ is not invertible (at least for some $t_0>0$) ?

Comment: @AndrásBátkai: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Exponential stability is of course equivalent to having $\|T(t_0)\| < 1$ for *at least one* time $t_0 > 0$. However, I think the OP asks for a characterization of the property $\|T(t)\| < 1$ for *all* $t > 0$ - which, I suppose, is a much more subtle question.

Comment: Hi, @JochenGlueck :-) You are right of course. But I perceived from the comments a different problem.I tried to give sufficient conditions, not characterization. Characterization is impossible at the moment...

Comment: @AndrásBátkai: I see, thanks for your reply. Having read the above comments once again I agree that the OP seems mostly interested in the question whether $1$ is in the resolvent set of $T(t)$ for each $t > 0$. For positive bounded semigroups this is, of course, equivalent to exponential stability of the semigroup.

Comment: @AndrásBátkai: Oh, and now I just noticed that the dependence on boundary conditions, which I remarked as a comment above, was already addressed earlier in your answer (so I deleted my comment about this issue). I guess I should read more carefully before commenting... ;-)

Comment: @JochenGlueck, Yeah, I need to know if 1 is in the resolvent set of $T(t)$ for all bounded semigroups associated with second order elliptic operators or not ?  I think it's not true in general, but I can't construct a counterexample.

Comment: @S.Cho: As András Batkai pointed out in his answer, this depends on the boundary conditions and on the domain $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ which you consider. Examples: Let your operator be the Laplace operator. (i) If $\Omega$ is bounded and you consider Neumann boundary conditions, then $1$ is an eigenvalues of $T(t)$ for each $t > 0$. (ii) If $\Omega$ is bounded and you consider Dirichlet boundary conditions, then $\|T(t)\| < 1$ for all $t > 0$. [to be continued]

Comment: @S.Cho: [continuation] (iii) If $\Omega$ is unbounded and you consider Dirichlet boundary conditions, then it can happen (depending on the precise shape of the $\Omega$) that $1$ is a spectral value of each operator $T(t)$. 
 [By the way, here I considered the semigroup on $L^2(\Omega)$, but similar results are true on $L^p(\Omega)$.]

Comment: @JochenGlueck: Thank you. Then the counterexample I'm looking for is the first (i). Can you recommend a good reference for more details (spectral theory of Laplacian or 2nd order elliptic operator in bounded domain).

Comment: @S.Cho: I added a reference to this.

Comment: @AndrásBátkai: Thank you very much !